# I am not able to enter Package Name URL under Facebook developers account for an app [Facebook]

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

We used to enter Google Play URL under "Package Names" for testing the app. But now we are getting an error "One or more invalid package name(s). Make sure package names are associated with a valid Google store URL".

I think it is related with a new Facebook's policy stating that there should be entered an URL of an app that is already in production. But then how to do the testing part? We need to test Facebook login feature in our app.

What should I do?[image]